# What does the Santa Strike do in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Per the new holiday update, Santa Strikes were introduced into the game.  What do they do / how do they work?

The in-game information & the patch description on this is [intentionally] ambiguous.  I haven't been able to find anyone to attack that had it.  It looks like a trap, so is it hidden until a troop sets it off?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe it is the same as the pumpkin bomb from the halloween update, but i don't know for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just triggered it in one of my attacks!   It is [holiday] trap, hidden until triggered by one of your troops.   It will proceed to pop open, pop red smoke, then Santa will carpet bomb the area with presents - which are bombs.

*I was able to capture some screen shots below of my reply*

**Troops triggering the trap:**
[image]

**Trap popping open (didn't seem like any damage was done here):**
[image]

**Red smoke, followed by Santa flying above it:**
[image]

**Present Carpet Bomb!**
[image]

**[AoE] Explosions!**

[image]

***Not much left* (but unsure of total damage in AoE):** There is no damage to attacking troops. The "trap" just drops presents with 5k elixir each. I was attacked recently and the archer that triggered it didn't die. Santa just flew by and drop 5 presents with 5k elixir a piece.
[image]

If you are on the receiving end of the attack and your Santa Strike is triggered, I found that it will leave presents for you to open near that attack.   **I gained 5,000 elixor per present.**

[image]

Comment: so in a nutshell, the santa strike is a defensive version of the lightning strike?

Comment: @Neffer_23 Basically yes, but with decent rewards per present you get back on each kill

Comment: okay thats cool

Answer (score 3):

Here is a video i did earlier where i set off one of these during a raid.

Answer (score 2):

It also leaves presents back for the user each present has 5000 or 50000 elixer when you click on the and it drops 5 presents or so. Pretty sure it's 5k each box but clan member said his was 50k we'll see

Answer (score 1):

Last year you could make a potion in your spell factory, it was called Santa's Surprise I think, which did exactly the same thing. If I remember that potion was listed as doing 1400-1500 damage, and the blast radius was much larger than a lightning spell.

It was specifically because of that spell the Clan Castle was updated last year to have more hit points, because attacking players were destroying the Clan Castle before the troops could be deployed.

Answer (score -4):

Wiki says that it leaves a surprise for when you log on after it's been triggered.